# Go program from Ubuntu 14.04 x86_64 won't run on Ubuntu 18.04 x86_64

Tags: go, cross-compiling, ubuntu-18.04

I have been using Go for quite a long time and currently I am stuck.

I started off with a `net/http program` that I had compiled on `Ubuntu 14.04 x86_64` and tried to run it on Amazon AWS EC2 running Ubuntu 18.04 on x86_64. It wouldn't work. I get `File Format Error`. I thought that maybe the `CGO` requirements were messing it up, so tried the `CGO_ENABLED=0` and `netgo` fix, didn't work.

I started removing all the code to see where the problem lies and currently my code is:

```
package main

import "fmt"

    func main() {
        fmt.Println("Hello")
   }
```

And my code still won't run. I have used the following build tags to be doubly sure:

`env GOARCH=amd64 GOOS=linux` but still all I get on the Ubuntu 18.04 is `Segmentation Fault (core dumped)`

Comment: how did you install go ?     https://golang.org/dl/    go is working fine on aws ec2 ubuntu 18.04

Comment: I installed go on my dev machine from golang.org/dl but, I don't have go compiler on my production machine for obvious reasons.

Comment: ok, so your dev machine is running Ubuntu 14.04?  And you compile on there and the binary doesn't work on 18.04?  Install the newest version of go on your dev machine and try again.  Also please add the uname -a outout for the dev machine and the EC2 to the question

Comment: `uname -a` is already there in the question. Thanks.

Comment: This is a 7 month old question. Did you find the explanation in the mean time ?

Comment: i would build the program using a docker image that replicates the target system.

Comment: I met the samiliar issue, but I compiled golang on ubuntu 22.04.1 but the target is ubuntu 20.04. it cannot run after cp to the target.